# Youtube Embed and Google-Fonts not working on "localhost" with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, https, certificate, self-signed

I need to convert a company website from HTTP to HTTPS.
In order to test it, they created for me a virtual machine (test environment) with a copy of the site that I can access using remote desktop.
This machine has IIS 7.5 installed. As a first step, I created a self-signed certificate and installed it, so now I can access the site on this machine with "https://127.0.0.1"

One of the problems is that various Google resources in their web-pages do not work - an iframe with Youtube refuses to open, Google Fonts do not work, etc. All of them warn me that my certificate was not issued by a trusted authority.
Is there some way to make them work?

I understand Google's reasoning, but the site is on localhost, so there is no attempt to fool anybody with this certificate. And anyway, what damage am I going to do to Youtube or Google Fonts?

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate Try to trust the test certificate.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li - you are right! Creating an appropariate certificate and "Trusting" it is the solution! While it is rather complicated to create an appropriate certificate to work with Chrome, it finally (after 3 hours) solved the problem. 
If you write your comment as an "Answer", I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from the comment.)

Self-signed certificates can lead to such warnings/errors due to

- Their signature algorithm might be insecure.
- Their Subject Alternative Name might be missing.
- They are not trusted by the web browser.

Thus, you need to use a proper tool to generate a good enough self-signed certificate, and also configure the browser to trust the certificate (like copying it to the user account's Trusted Root Authorities store.

Jexus Manager can generate such certificates, and also trust them,

https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/self-signed.html